# What is this high-wing jet airplane?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]

Can someone help me in identifying this plane?

Answer (score 21):

[image]
([planespotters.net](https://www.planespotters.net/photo/179370/a6-rj2-dubai-air-wing-royal-flight-british-aerospace-avro-rj85))

The flag is an easy giveaway. It's [one of two](https://www.planespotters.net/production-list/search?fleet=Dubai-Air-Wing-Royal-Flight&manufacturer=British-Aerospace&subtype=Avro-RJ85&fleetStatus=current)* British Aerospace Avro [RJ85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Aerospace_146#BAe_146-200_and_Avro_RJ85)'s operated by [Dubai Royal Air Wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubai_Royal_Air_Wing).

* Probably it's the A6-RJ2 (but the registration is blurry).

Answer (score 7):

It's probably a Bae 146-200 / Avro RJ

Here is the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Aerospace_146).

If you want to know if it's really a [-200](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BAe_146) you could try and count windows or measure relative lengths.